# Make a React table sortable alphabetically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

There is a component, `GenericTable` that receives as attributes the data.

in the component which has the data:

```
const headers = ['ID', 'Name', 'City'];
const rows = [{cells: ['1', 'John', 'Paris']},
              {cells: ['3', 'Ben', 'Berlin']},
              {cells: ['2', 'Helen', 'Barcelona']}
              ];
const idList = ['1', '3', '2'];
```

---

```
<GenericTable
  headers={headers}
  rows={rows}
  idList={idList}
/>
```

in GenericTable:

```
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class GenericTable extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { headers, rows, idList } = this.props;
    
    return (
      <Table>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
             {headers.map(header => (
                <Table.HeaderCell key={headers.indexOf(header)}>
                 {header}
                </Table.HeaderCell>
             )}
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body>
          {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
            <Table.Row key={idList && idList[rowIndex]}>
                <Table.Cell>
                  ...
                </Table.Cell>
         
            </Table.Row>
          )}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make the table sortable? For example, add a button near **name** header and when it is clicked to sort the table alphabetically based on that column?

I've tried to solve it but it doesn't work. I added the default value in the state, a button for each column header which can be clicked, and when it's clicked it should sort the data based on that column:

```
  import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class GenericTable extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { // added state
      currentSort: 'default',
    };
  }

onSortChange = () => { // added method
  const { currentSort } = this.state;
  let nextSort;

  if (currentSort === 'down') nextSort = 'up';
  else if (currentSort === 'up') nextSort = 'default';
  else if (currentSort === 'default') nextSort = 'down';

  this.setState({
    currentSort: nextSort,
  });
};

  render() {

    const { currentSort } = this.state; // added state
    const sortTypes = { // added constant
      up: {
       class: 'sort-up',
       fn: (a, b) => a.name - b.name,
      },
      down: {
        class: 'sort-down',
        fn: (a, b) => b.name - a.name,
      },
     default: {
       class: 'sort',
       fn: (a, b) => a,
     },
   };
    const { headers, rows, idList } = this.props;
    
    return (
      <Table>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
             {headers.map(header => (
                <Table.HeaderCell key={headers.indexOf(header)}>
                 {header}
                 // added button
                 <button onClick={this.onSortChange} type="button">
                   <i className={`fas fa-${sortTypes[currentSort].class}`} />
                 </button>
                </Table.HeaderCell>
             )}
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body>
         // added below
          {[...rows].sort(sortTypes[currentSort].fn).map((row, rowIndex) => (
            <Table.Row key={idList && idList[rowIndex]}>
                <Table.Cell>
                  ...
                </Table.Cell>
         
            </Table.Row>
          )}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can safe the rows prop in the component state. If the table header is clicked you can update the state with the onSortChange function

```
<Table.Row>
      {headers.map((header,index) => (
            <Table.HeaderCell key={headers.indexOf(header)}>
             {header}
             // added below
             <button onClick={() => this.onSortChange(index)} type="button">
          <i className={`fas fa-${sortTypes[currentSort].class}`} />
             </button>
            </Table.HeaderCell>
         )}
</Table.Row>

onSortChange = (i) => { // added method
  var newRows = rows.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.cells[i] < b.cells[i]) { return -1; }
    if(a.cells[i] > b.cells[i]) { return 1; }
    return 0;
  })
  this.setState({rows: newRows})
};
```

/Edit
I did an example here

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-elbakyan-g9tw5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: what do you mean by safe the rows props in the state? I added in `this.state = { rows: '' }` and it should be modified at the end on your modified function `onSortChange` but unfortunately it does not work. It doesn't compile because it returns an error: `unused state field rows`. Is it wrong how I put it in the state?

Comment: I made you an example in codesandbox and edited the post

Comment: I was expecting that `onSortChange` to do the reverse alphabetical order when it is clicked second time. the two IFs from that method aren't responsible for that?

Comment: No, the 2 Ifs are just for shifting the values.
You can provide an other state which column is currently sorted and if its ascending or descending. In case of that turn the sort function around. I updated the example

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can implement sorting using lodash. Note am using Hooks although I see you are still using classes but you should still be able to use the code either way. Just need to use component state instead of the useReducer hook. You can also use vanilla JS instead of lodash.

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import React from 'react'
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const headers = ['ID', 'Name', 'City'];

const rows = [{cells: ['1', 'John', 'Paris']},
              {cells: ['3', 'Ben', 'Berlin']},
              {cells: ['2', 'Helen', 'Barcelona']}
              ];

const columnsData = rows.map(row => { 
  return {ID: row.cells[0], Name: row.cells[1], City: row.cells[2] }
})

function tableReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_SORT':
      if (state.column === action.column) {
        return {
          ...state,
          data: state.data.reverse(),
          direction:
            state.direction === 'ascending' ? 'descending' : 'ascending',
        }
      }

      return {
        column: action.column,
        data: _.sortBy(state.data, [action.column]),
        direction: 'ascending',
      }
    default:
      throw new Error()
  }
}


function TableExampleSortable() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(tableReducer, {
    column: null,
    data: columnsData,
    direction: null,
  })
  const { column, data, direction } = state

  return (
    <Table>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
             {headers.map(header => (
                <Table.HeaderCell key={headers.indexOf(header)}
                sorted={column === header ? direction : null}
                onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_SORT', column: header })}>
                 {header}
                </Table.HeaderCell>
             ))}
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body>
        {data.map(({ ID, Name, City }) => (
          <Table.Row key={ID}>
            <Table.Cell>{ID}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{Name}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{City}</Table.Cell>
          </Table.Row>
        ))}
      </Table.Body>

      </Table>
  )
}

export default TableExampleSortable
```